# Sorting out the data in a mongodb database by repeating fields

Tags: mongodb, sorting, database

First of all I'm still pretty green about the MongoDB. I have a question about how to sort out the data in the database I have. DB contains venues collection in which I have some entries. Each entry has cities and some of them has review IDs in arrays. So I want to arrange it in the way so I have cities and number of reviews that are made in each one.

I only been able to take out all the venues that has no reviews by using:

```
db.venues.find(
{reviewdata: {$ne:[]}},
{city:1,reviewdata:1,_id:0}
)
```

I'm pretty much stuck stuck because if I want to aggregate the additional data and group it by cities and sort by amount of reviews I cannot do it. Is there a way to combine *.find()* and *.aggregate()* functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `.aggregate()` and [`$match`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRqYW-hrXOAhVDfhoKHaiRATMQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mongodb.com%2Fmanual%2Freference%2Foperator%2Faggregation%2Fmatch&usg=AFQjCNGab9yUmn4n9jZe91F1LEDahcnFYg):

> Filters the documents to pass only the documents that match the specified condition(s) to the next pipeline stage.

```
db.venues.aggregate([
  {$match:
    { reviewdata: { $ne:[] } },
    { city:1, reviewdata:1, _id:0 }
  },
  { $group: { 
    _id: "$city", // Or however you'd group it. Would need document input/output example
    count: { $sum: 1 } // You can also add accumulator expressions, like this
  }
])
```